# Robot FW : BuiltIn Library : "Reload Library" keyword : How to use "Reload Library" keyword in a robot library?

Tags: robotframework

Acc.to [the documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Reload%20Library)

```
Reload Library        name_or_instance
```

> Rechecks what keywords the specified library provides.
>     Can be called explicitly in the test data or by a library itself when keywords it provides 
>     have changed. The library can be specified by its name or as the active instance of the 
>     library. The latter is especially useful if the library itself calls this keyword as a 
>     method. New in Robot Framework 2.9.

**The goal:**

Is to provide a concrete example 1, where a library A uses `Reload Library  LibraryB` and checks that the keywords `LibraryB` provides indeed have changed.

Another example 2 would be to use the `Reload Library  LibraryB` in the test data and check that the keywords `LibraryB` provides indeed have changed.

With the given documentation, i am unable to provide such an example. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: When you say _"where a client library uses Reload Library  LibraryX "_ - in your mind are "client library" and "LibraryX" the same thing, or are you asking about two libraries A and B, where A uses B and then reloads B? Also, why do you need to verify that the keywords have changed? Do you not trust that the keyword does what it says it does?

Comment: In my mind, library A uses library B and then reloads B via the "Reload Library" keyword. But i do not understand how keywords in Library B change and how library A can utilize the newly changed keywords in B. This concept is totally unclear, therefore i ask for examples.